# SQL server Assertion failed error while sending mail with Excel or PDF attachments

Tags: sql-server

I used to send mails from SQL server using the sp_send_dbmail with attachments.
But for the past 10 days the mails are not triggered. I checked the procedure and tried it without the attachments and it works. If an Excel or a PDF attachment is there, the procedure throws the below error...

---

```
Location:    SpcAlloc.cpp:914
Expression:  pPage->IsType (Page::TEXT_MIX_PAGE)
SPID:        89
Process ID:  2108
Msg 3624, Level 20, State 1, Procedure sp_send_dbmail, Line 449
A system assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server error log for details. Typically,
an assertion failure is caused by a software bug or data corruption. To check for database
corruption, consider running DBCC CHECKDB. If you agreed to send dumps to Microsoft during
setup, a mini dump will be sent to Microsoft. An update might be available from Microsoft
in the latest Service Pack or in a QFE from Technical Support. 
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

---

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: So, have you run `DBCC CHECKDB`? Otherwise, I think you need to post your code. Have you updated MSSQL or drivers recently?

Answer (score 0):

you will see more details in sqlserver error log and errorlog points out to dump location as well..

Right now,here are your options

1.Try checking if you are on the latest version of sqlserver and if you are not try upgrading to latest CU or SP
2.If you get this error even after  upgrading to latest CU or SP,try contacting microsoft support

IF you are latest version of sqlserver,you will have more luck as it has some [extensions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/sql-server-diagnostics-preview/) like  [SQL Server Diagnostics (Preview)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=55516)   .Once you are done installing this extension, you will provide below screen to upload dump

[image]

after uploading,SSMS will analyze the dumps for you and present relevant KB's like below

[image]